# Can't use vuejs component in template

Tags: vue.js

I have a vuejs application with typescript and webpack. I tried to make a form component for adding new customers. For that I have a .vue file:

```
<template>
    <v-dialog max-width="600px">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                <div>
                    <h3 class="headline primary--text">Account</h3>
                </div>
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer />
                <v-btn flat @click="cancel">cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="primary" flat :disabled="!validFormData" @click="submit">save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script src="./CustomerForm.ts"></script>
```

And the CustomerForm.ts:

```
import { Prop, Vue, } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
import { Customer } from "../../../types/Customer";

@Component
export default class CustomerForm extends Vue {
    @Prop()
    customer!: Customer;

    @Prop()
    value!: boolean;

    validFormData: boolean = true;

    submit() {
        if ((<HTMLFormElement>this.$refs.form).validate()) {
            this.$emit('save', this.customer)
        }
    }

    cancel() {
        (<HTMLFormElement>this.$refs.form).reset();
        this.$emit('input');
    }
}
```

Now I want to include that in my parent template that I can open it when "showForm" is true:

```
<customer-form v-model="showForm"/>
```

But I always get this error:

```
Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <CustomerForm>
...
```

I try to import it with this:

```
import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import CustomerForm from "./CustomerForm";


@Component({
    components: {
        CustomerForm
    }
})
export default class CustomerManagement extends Vue {
...
}
```

I assume that I have something wrong with referencing the component?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include this like following?

```
import CustomerForm from '@/../CustomerFormComponent.vue';

@Component({components:{CustomerForm}})
export default class ParentClass extends Vue {
```

Also `<customer-form v-model="showForm"/>` is wrong for your waiting behavior it should be like this `<customer-form v-if="showForm"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the import code to my question. What I wonder is if the issue is that CustomerForm references to the .ts file instead of the .vue. Is it possible that the system can't find the relation between these two?

Comment: did you try to import Vue file instead of ts?

Comment: yes, but that leads to issues with typescript since he cannot find the type.

Comment: After reading https://medium.com/js-dojo/7-ways-to-define-a-component-template-in-vuejs-c04e0c72900d  it looks like: need to try to change`<template> ` to `<customer-form inline-template>`